# ImportError: No module named bottle -- WSGI + python + apache

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bottle

I'm trying to run a bottle app on my apache Amazon EC2 server through WSGI, and I keep getting this error:

```
[Fri Aug 12 06:15:13 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5]   File "/var/www/html/website/app.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Fri Aug 12 06:15:13 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5]     import bottle
[Fri Aug 12 06:15:13 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5] ImportError: No module named bottle
```

When I installed mod_wsgi, this was used:

```
mod_wsgi-python26-3.2-6.11.amzn1.x86_64
```

Here is my app.wsgi file

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/website")

import bottle
import app

application = bottle.default_app()
```

Here is my httpd.conf:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName website.website.me
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website

WSGIDaemonProcess website threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/website/app.wsgi
        <Directory "/var/www/html/website">
                WSGIProcessGroup website
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the version of WSGI (from my error log):

```
[Fri Aug 12 06:15:11 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.29 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

But if I run `python -V`, I get `Python 2.7.10`.

Also I know bottle is installed correctly because when I do the following, there's no error:

```
$ python
>>>import bottle #no import error
>>>
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried doing a "hello world" test to see if wsgi was working:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

It worked, so the problem is not WSGI.

This is what is inside my app.py file:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, static_file, request
import main


template = """<html>
<head><title>Home</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Upload a file</h1>
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Category:      <input type="text" name="category" />
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload1" />
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload2" />
  <input type="submit" value="Start upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>"""


@route('/')
def index():
    return template
```

If I execute `python app.py`, there are no errors. It's just when I refresh website.website.me that there is the 500 error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you don't have folder permisions

Comment: Which folder? @Raskayu

Comment: Where is the `bottle.py` file?  The Python environment you get when running `python` from the shell is likely not the same as the one the webserver creates.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling bottle from your directory and then open cmd and run it as administrater and type pip install bottle and see for yourself...

```
   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install bottle
Collecting bottle
  Using cached bottle-0.12.9.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: bottle
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for bottle ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\hkpra\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\6e\87\89\f7ddd6721f4a208d44f2dac02f281b2403a314dd735d2b0e61
Successfully built bottle
Installing collected packages: bottle
Successfully installed bottle-0.12.9
```

Comment: Already tried re-installing bottle and reinstalling mod_wsgi -- neither have worked...